# ActiveRecord query with multiple nested relations for the same model in where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using:

- Ruby 2.6.5
- Rails 6.0.2.1
- PostgreSQL 11

**The problem:**

I'm trying to create a Scope query for Pundit to check if user has an access to the secret (password) that it wants to visit. I tried to join/include nested users within teams/projects and users which have an access to the password with in such way (writing from what I remember):

**What I tried**

```rb
# secret_policy.rb
class SecretPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      test = scope.includes(:projects => {:teams => :users}).includes(:teams => 
      {:users}).includes(:users)
      test.where(projects: {teams: {users: {id: user}}})
            .or(test.where(teams: {users: {id: user}}).or(test.where(users: {id: user})))
    end
  end
# [...]
end
```

and then in controller:

```rb
# secret_controller.rb
class SecretController < ApplicationController
[...]
  def show
    @secret = policy_scope(Secret).find(params[:id])
  end
[...]
end
```

which was supposed to join all related entities to `Secret` model and do nested queries but what was happening at the end was that even tho `includes` worked properly including all needed data, at the end `where` clause was using the same join name for running a query: `users` which is wrong because different join names containing needed data should be called.

---

**More details:**

I have a structure like so:

```rb
# user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
  has_and_belongs_to_many :secrets
end
```

```rb
# secret.rb
class Secret < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end
```

```rb
# team.rb
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :secrets
end
```

```rb
# project.rb
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :teams
  has_and_belongs_to_many :secrets
end
```

I'm kinda new to Rails (ActiveRecords) so my mapping might be a bit wrong. Here is what it supposed to be just to make it clear:

User:

- can be owner of passwords
- can have access to passwords given by other users
- can belong to teams
- can belong to projects

Secret:

- can belong to 1 user
- can be shared with many teams
- can be shared with many users (not including owner. Owner has an access already)
- can be shared with many projects

Team:

- can belong to 1 project
- belongs to only 1 user
- many users can join the team
- many secrets can be shared within the team

Projects:

- belongs to only 1 user
- can have many teams (uniquely)
- many secrets can be shared within the projects

I found many resources talking about the case when you can do it with nested relations but usually it was done with only 1 resource being in where clause, so there was no issue with incorrectly used joins. I was about to give up and try to rewrite is in native SQL, but I believe there must be something.